# Update database by sending emails in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, email, codeigniter-datamapper

I am using codeigniter with datamapper orm

i want to update things using email messages

for example there are tables named "projects" and "messages"

projects
id / name

messages
id / content / project_id

each project has many messages and a name.

what i want is, if I send a message to project_id@domain
a new message be inserted into messages with that email content

is there any perfect way to do this ?

ty

Answer (score 0):

Indeed there is a relatively elegant way to handle this. You need to extend Codeigniters E-Mail library and override the send () method. After sending do your database stuff. I might give you a code example as soon as I'm not on my phone anymore.